# F#: Printing full lists without explicit loop

Tags: f#

Is it possible to print a data structure in `F#` without abbreviating long lists?

With printf I can only seem to print the first 100 elements:

```
\> let l = [1 .. 200];;

val l : int list =
  [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; 13; 14; 15; 16; 17; 18; 19; 20; 21;
   22; 23; 24; 25; 26; 27; 28; 29; 30; 31; 32; 33; 34; 35; 36; 37; 38; 39; 40;
   41; 42; 43; 44; 45; 46; 47; 48; 49; 50; 51; 52; 53; 54; 55; 56; 57; 58; 59;
   60; 61; 62; 63; 64; 65; 66; 67; 68; 69; 70; 71; 72; 73; 74; 75; 76; 77; 78;
   79; 80; 81; 82; 83; 84; 85; 86; 87; 88; 89; 90; 91; 92; 93; 94; 95; 96; 97;
   98; 99; 100; ...]

\> printf "%A\n" l;;   
[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; 13; 14; 15; 16; 17; 18; 19; 20; 21; 22;
 23; 24; 25; 26; 27; 28; 29; 30; 31; 32; 33; 34; 35; 36; 37; 38; 39; 40; 41; 42;
 43; 44; 45; 46; 47; 48; 49; 50; 51; 52; 53; 54; 55; 56; 57; 58; 59; 60; 61; 62;
 63; 64; 65; 66; 67; 68; 69; 70; 71; 72; 73; 74; 75; 76; 77; 78; 79; 80; 81; 82;
 83; 84; 85; 86; 87; 88; 89; 90; 91; 92; 93; 94; 95; 96; 97; 98; 99; 100; ...]

val it : unit = ()
```

In this case it would be possible to loop through the elements, however, in a more complicated data structure it would be necessary to decompose the structure to allow access to the lists.

For example, is it possible to print the following structure in its entirety without breaking it down into individual lists:

```
\> let l = ([1 ..200], [1..200]);;
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `PrintLength` property of the `fsi` object to specify maximal length for printing lists. It doesn't allow you to specify infinity directly, but you can use:

```
fsi.PrintLength <- System.Int32.MaxValue
```

There are several similar properties, but they aren't documented very well (see the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee842563.aspx)), so you'll probably need to experiment a bit.

Comment: This does change the number of elements displayed interactively, however it does not change the output formatted by printf.

Comment: @user734239: I looked around in the source code a bit. The `PrintLength` value for `printf` seems to be hardcoded to be 100. (`formatOne` in `printf.fs` uses `FormatOptions.Default` for the `%A`case. `FormatOptions.Default` is a static read-only property.)